# wifi flaked out

Tags: networking, network-manager, ubuntu-mate

I have 2 lenovo thinkpads, both running Ubuntu mate 17.04 zesty.
At some point, the T430, stopped connecting to the internet. I was able to see other networks, but not able to connect to my home network. 
I swapped the hard drives, and am now able to connect with both laptops. 
This would seem to rule out hardware malfunctions. I would however like to return things to the normal set up.

I tried to follow this tutorial, but couldn't find nm-tool.
lspci, lshw -C network both listed the hardware.

demesg reported the device was active, but failed to restart. 
There seemed to be many IPV6 related errors.

I can recreate these problems later, after I do my work.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you running Ubuntu 17.04 ("Zesty") or an Ubuntu 17.10  beta?

Comment: Ah yeh, its zesty, is that 17.04? I talked to my ISP, and they are replacing my modem with something that has IPV6 support. Im not sure if it is an IPV6 related issue.